# Python mysql.connector как правильно делать запросы к бд что подключение не падало?

Tags: python, mysql

Делаю запросы к бд по этим примерам
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp
Заметил что если некоторое время не делать запросов к бд (примерно минуту) а потом послать - пишет что подключение уже было закрыто. С чем это связанно? Как вообще правильно подключатся к БД с этой библиотекой, нужно ли делать mydb.close() после каждого обращения? Буду рад любым примерам

Comment: я использовал библиотеку MySQLdb, но они почти похожи. Необходимо для каждого запроса создавать новое соединение и сразу закрывать его

Comment: возможно все дело в настройках самого MySQL. Посмотри [здесь](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/tnastroyka.html)

Comment: Если в каждой функции прописываю mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="xx.xx.xx",
    user="xxx",
    passwd="xxx",
    database="xxxx"
    ) Потом объявляю курсор, делаю sql запрос и закрываю - то все хорошо работает. Но правильный ли такой подход? Не слишком много кода?...

Comment: Используйте [connection pooling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае стоит воспользоваться [Connection Pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool).

Пример с использованием [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#connection-timeouts):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test", pool_recycle=3600)
```

[Связанный вопрос из англоязычной версии SO со многими полезными ссылками ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8825024/5741205)